# Outlook ole error 800A01A8 when closing it with more than 10 outlook-explorer windows

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole, outlook-addin

I have written an Outlook plugin in Delphi 2009 that opens a database connection and does some tasks to accompany my main application.
When Outlook is now closed it raises an 800A01A8 ole error, but only if you had about 10 outlook-explorer windows open. Another important point is that that only happens occasionally when you use File\Exit to close all windows at once, but much more often, even so not always, when you close them all at once using the windows taskbar close all feature.
When attaching the debugger I could not find where that error is fired.
I am kind of lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook ole error 800A01A8 = Object required.

Object Required is a server component, typically an update component or mail component. You are trying to use such an object which is already destroyed.

Perhaps you add a runtime stack tracer. For example madExcept, EurekaLog or JEDI [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/)'s JCL is the only free offering from the above. In order to generate an Error Dialog for your program with the Stack Trace in it go to File | New Items | Delphi Files | "JCL Exception Dialog for Delphi".

With such a tool, when the error is raised at runtime you will see the stack trace which will help you to diagnose the problem.

HTH